# Inside div css settings

Tags: html, css

I created a div with "commonDiv" id (example), then is create multiple divs inside it, div, div in divs etc. All divs contains button(s). I want to add a common style for the buttons. I'd like to add a css only one settings for it.

I tried the following but it's not worked:

```css
div#commonDiv .button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}
```

What's the right way?

Comment: As i can see it seems about right, is it working or are you just asking best practices?

Comment: Sorry, it's work. Somewhere else is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
div#commonDiv button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}
```

I removed the period before `.button`.

The rules you declared didn't match the `<button>` tag but any element that has class "button"...

*If it doesn't solve your issue feel free to leave a comment.*

Comment: Thanks it's work fine. There was an other problem too in my code, and thats why that didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Well the best way is mentioning class for all of your `<div>`s and then adding style in the CSS code using your class.

```
.your_class_name {write any style you want for all of them !}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see a very good document about CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). And if your buttons have not any class may be this code fix your problem:

```
div#commonDiv button{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution which is the following: div#commonDiv input[type=button]